Self-written Tasks Queue and awaiting for specific task
Good evening!
I've been busy writing a task queue using Node.js for my pet projects, which allows me to wait for a specific task to be completed. The queue works well until it receives a large asynchronous load like this:
const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    promises.push(queue.enqueueAndWait(task))
}
await Promise.allSettled(promises);

And I get output like this:
[2024-08-11 21:14:59] [App] error: ActionsQueue | BAD_ENTRANCE
[2024-08-11 21:14:59] [ScenariosService] error: BAD_ENTRANCE
[2024-08-11 21:14:59] [ActionsCalls] info: [Marlo]     The fight ended successfully. You have win.
[2024-08-11 21:15:00] [App] error: ActionsQueue | LOST_WAITED_TASK Lost b828e754-2333-4c6b-882a-b9979e83de15 task!
[2024-08-11 21:15:00] [ScenariosService] error: LOST_WAITED_TASK


Can you provide me with any ideas on how to improve my concept, or at least suggest other ways to achieve this queue goal?
You can get the code from the link, I will also provide it below:
https://github.com/neuroborus/tasks-mad-queue/blob/main/src/queue/tasks-queue.service.ts
import { randomUUID, UUID } from 'crypto';
import {
  TasksQueueErrorCodes,
  TasksQueueFuncType,
  ITasksQueueConfig,
} from '../entities';
import { TasksQueueElement } from './tasks-queue.element';
import { EMPTY_FUNC } from './tasks-queue.empty-func-constant';
import { TasksQueueDefaultConfig } from './tasks-queue.default-config';

export class TasksQueueService {
  private readonly config: ITasksQueueConfig;
  private tasks: TasksQueueElement[] = [];
  private isQueueRunning = false;

  private currentProcess: Promise<unknown> = EMPTY_FUNC();
  private awaitedTasks: Set<string> = new Set();
  private attemptCounter: Map<string, number> = new Map();

  constructor(config: Partial<ITasksQueueConfig> = {}) {
    this.config = {
      ...TasksQueueDefaultConfig,
      ...config,
    };
  }

  // API

  public start(): void {
    this.influxProcess();
  }

  public enqueue(func: TasksQueueFuncType): void {
    this.validations();
    this.enqueueInnerInflux(func);
  }

  public enqueueAndWait<T>(func: TasksQueueFuncType<T>): Promise<T> {
    this.validations();
    return this.enqueueInnerAndWait<T>(func);
  }

  public getConfig(): ITasksQueueConfig {
    return this.config;
  }

  public async wait(): Promise<void> {
    await this.currentProcess;
    return;
  }

  public isRunning(): boolean {
    return this.isQueueRunning;
  }

  // Service

  private taskDestructor(taskId: string): void {
    this.attemptCounter.delete(taskId);
    this.awaitedTasks.delete(taskId);
  }

  private async sleepWithDelay(): Promise<void> {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, this.config.delayMS);
    });
  }

  private capacityValidation(): void {
    if (this.tasks.length >= this.config.capacity) {
      this.config.logger?.error?.(
        `${this.config.label} | ${this.tasks.length} capacity validation failed`,
      );
      throw new Error(TasksQueueErrorCodes.FULL_CAPACITY);
    }
  }

  private validations(): void {
    this.capacityValidation();
  }

  // Processors

  private enqueueInnerInflux(
    func: TasksQueueFuncType,
    taskId: UUID = randomUUID(),
  ): void {
    this.tasks.push({ func, id: taskId });
    if (this.config.nonWaitAutoProcess) this.influxProcess();
  }

  private async enqueueInnerAndWait<T>(
    func: TasksQueueFuncType<T>,
    taskId = randomUUID(),
  ): Promise<T> {
    this.tasks.push({ func, id: taskId });
    this.awaitedTasks.add(taskId);
    const result = (await this.waitForTurn<T>(taskId)) as T;
    if (this.config.nonWaitAutoProcess) this.influxProcess();
    return result;
  }

  private async waitForTurn<T>(taskId: UUID): Promise<T | null> {
    // Create new
    const process = async () => {
      // Wait for process
      await this.currentProcess;
      return await this.processTasks<T>(taskId);
    };

    // Set new process as current
    const waitedProcess = process();
    this.currentProcess = waitedProcess;
    return waitedProcess;
  }

  private influxProcess() {
    if (!this.isQueueRunning) this.currentProcess = this.processTasks();
  }

  // noinspection t
  private async processTasks<T>(waitFor?: UUID): Promise<T | null> {
    if (this.isQueueRunning) {
      if (waitFor) {
        this.config.logger?.fatal?.(
          `${this.config.label} | ${TasksQueueErrorCodes.BAD_ENTRANCE}`,
        );
        throw new Error(TasksQueueErrorCodes.BAD_ENTRANCE);
      }
      return null;
    }

    this.isQueueRunning = true;

    this.config.logger?.trace?.(
      `${this.config.label} | Process tasks started. Tasks in queue -> ${this.tasks.length}`,
    );

    const isWaitFor = (taskId: UUID) => waitFor === taskId;

    while (this.tasks.length > 0) {
      if (
        this.awaitedTasks.has(this.tasks[0].id) &&
        !isWaitFor(this.tasks[0].id)
      ) {
        if (!waitFor) {
          // Give control of waited task to waitFor function
          this.isQueueRunning = false;
          return null;
        } else {
          this.config.logger?.fatal?.(
            `${this.config.label} | ${TasksQueueErrorCodes.LOST_WAITED_TASK} Lost ${waitFor} task!`,
          );
          throw new Error(TasksQueueErrorCodes.LOST_WAITED_TASK);
        }
      }

      const task = this.tasks.shift();
      if (!task) {
        this.config.logger?.fatal?.(
          `${this.config.label} | ${TasksQueueErrorCodes.LOST_TASK}`,
        );
        throw new Error(TasksQueueErrorCodes.LOST_TASK);
      }

      this.config.logger?.trace?.(
        `${this.config.label} | Process task ${task.id} | Tasks in queue -> ${
          this.tasks.length
        }${waitFor ? ` | Waited for -> ${waitFor}` : ''}`,
      );

      let result = {} as T;
      let err: unknown;

      await this.sleepWithDelay();
      try {
        result = (await task.func()) as T;
        this.taskDestructor(task.id);
      } catch (e: unknown) {
        err = e;
        if (!isWaitFor(task.id)) {
          this.config.logger?.error?.(
            `${this.config.label} | Task ${task.id} -> ${e}`,
          );
          // Retries only for non-waited tasks
          const retriesCounter = this.attemptCounter.get(task.id) || 0;
          if (retriesCounter < this.config.nonWaitRetriesPerTask) {
            this.config.logger?.trace?.(
              `${this.config.label} | Retry task -> ${task.id}`,
            );
            this.attemptCounter.set(task.id, retriesCounter + 1);
            this.enqueueInnerInflux(task.func, task.id);
          } else {
            this.taskDestructor(task.id);
          }
        }
      } finally {
        this.config.logger?.trace?.(
          `${this.config.label} | Processed ${task.id}${
            waitFor ? ` | Waited for -> ${waitFor}` : ''
          }`,
        );
      }
      if (isWaitFor(task.id)) {
        this.currentProcess = EMPTY_FUNC(); // Q: What if waiting query would grow? A: an instant assignment in influxProcess()
        this.taskDestructor(task.id);
        this.isQueueRunning = false;
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          return result;
        }
      }
    }

    this.currentProcess = EMPTY_FUNC();
    this.isQueueRunning = false;
    return null;
  }
}

